# как динамический менять appBar title при скроллинге?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
как динамический менять `title` в `AppBar` при скроллинге, как на этой гифке:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  ScrollController controller = ScrollController();
  Widget appBarTitle = Text('title');

  @override
  void initState() {
    onScrolling();
    super.initState();
  }

  void onScrolling(){
    if(controller.position.pixels > 200){
      setState(() {
        appBarTitle = RaisedButton(onPressed: (){}, child: Text('title'),);
      });
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: appBarTitle,
      ),
      body: ListView(
        controller: controller,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 1200,
            color: Colors.amberAccent,
          ),
          Container(
            height: 1200,
            color: Colors.green,
          ),
          Container(
            height: 1200,
            color: Colors.yellow
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

нашел такой способ:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    controller = ScrollController();
    controller.addListener(_onScrolling);
    super.initState();
  }

  _onScrolling(){
    if (controller.offset >= 200 && !controller.position.outOfRange) {
      setState(() {
        appBarTitle = RaisedButton(onPressed: (){}, child: Text('data'),);
      });
    } else if (controller.offset <= 200 * 2 &&
        !controller.position.outOfRange) {
      setState(() {
        appBarTitle = Text('title');
      });
    }
  }
```

но теперь при скроллинге жутко тормозит